# Is there any reason *NOT* to define a MutationObserver callback using an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, callback, arrow-functions, mutation-observers

I'm learning to drink the ES6 koolaid ...

I've read that there are contexts where using a ES6 "arrow function" is not a good idea.  I think the main one where the "this" variable is expected, like in methods.  Is there a problem using an arrow function to define a callback; specifically for a Mutation Observer, like this:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
      mutations.forEach(mutation => {
         // do stuff...
       });
   });
```

This works in Chrome.  Haven't tried other browsers.

Comment: In this case it's just a matter of personal preference. Note that most examples for MutationObserver are outdated and were written before the arrow syntax became popular.

Comment: Using `this` in the `MutationObserver` constructor is superfluous since it has the same value as the second parameter of the callback.

Comment: A reviewer provided link to a "similar question" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable).  I would propose that post shows "here's how to do it with arrow functions".  *NOT* the question I'm asking, which is "is this a context where I DON'T want to use arrow functions".  In any case this thread has been terminated.